# ngx-bootstrap-accordion hide/show when button is clicked

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, ngx-bootstrap

I have animated `ngx-bootstrap-accordion`
but if I click fastly enough the label is not consist with state of `accordion`. I want the label to say `hide` if there is something to hide, not when the content is visible.

**Update example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-accordion-asasasa2-zb5ki6**

**See blitz here:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-accordion-asasasa2

`app.component.ts`

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AccordionPanelComponent } from 'ngx-bootstrap/accordion';
import {AfterViewInit, Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {ViewportScroller} from '@angular/common';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { StorageService, SESSION_STORAGE} from 'ngx-webstorage-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  sections = [
    {
      code: 'a',
      visible: true,
      subsections: null
    },
    {
      code: 'p',
      visible: true,
      subsections: null
    }
  ];
}
```

`app.component.html`

```
<div class="toolbar">
    <h2>Toolbar</h2>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <accordion [isAnimated]="true">
        <accordion-group *ngFor="let subsection of sections" [isOpen]="subsection.visible" class="app-accordion-group">

            <div class="app-subsection-accordion-header" accordion-heading >

                <button *ngIf="subsection.visible"  (click)="subsection.visible = !subsection.visible">
               Open panel 2
             </button>

                <button *ngIf="!subsection.visible" (click)="subsection.visible = !subsection.visible">
              Hide panel 2
            </button>

                <div class="app-header-title">
                    text
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="app-document app-desktopVisible">
                doc
            </div>
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mutating visible property on template the reference of object is not changing so accordion component change detection is not get triggered.

**Try this:**

**component.html**

```
    <button *ngIf="subsection.visible"  (click)="toggle(i)">
           Open panel
     </button>
```

**component.ts**

```
toggle(index){
    this.sections[index] = {
      ... this.sections[index],visible: ! this.sections[index].visible
 }
}
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-accordion-asasasa2-f2dxtk)

Comment: Just adding the code to `component.ts` does not solve this - see in blitz. The code from the html is the same. I want it to say `Open panel` if there's content hidden, and `Hide panel` if there's content visible. The content says `doc` in the example. Try clicking the button `hide/show panel` fastly in `blitz`. I can make it say `Hide panel` when the `doc` word is hidden.

Comment: Maybe the example was not perfect, note that we are operating on `subsection` not `section` in html. We want to hide/show `subsections`. The `doc` text could be text from `subsection` and it should not be null. I will update it.

Comment: I have added updated example, i want to operate on `subsections` and i want to disable default accordion behaviour that's hiding/showing content when clickend on it, i want it to only hide/show when I will click the button. Sorry, for the previous not precise example. I wanted the sections to be visible from the start, but subsections should be visible after mouse click on the button.

Comment: The issues what is left here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-accordion-asasasa2-zb5ki6
Is to prevent accordion from it's own behavior, when clicking on it - it should react only to button.

The `minor` issue, but it's only in `blitz` that the sections don't react to `[isOpen]="true"` correctly due to ```ERROR
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'panel-open: true'. Current value: 'panel-open: false'```

Comment: You mean all section shoulds be visible by default?

Comment: yes, `sections` yes, `subsections` no. I will add `(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"` to example. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Accordion is made up of a number of expandable/collapsible items. Only one item is ever shown at a time that's how accordion will react, that's why accordion only showing last accordion as opened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209146/discussion-between-tryinghard-and-chellappan-).